# how to let install4j know not to remove certain files when uninstalling

Tags: java, install4j

I have a requirement that certain files i copy during the installation (by running a script) need to be kept even when application uninstalled. how this can be achieved in install4j?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a "Copy files and directories" action to copy those files during the installation, you can set its "Uninstall mode" property to "Never" to prevent the copied files from getting uninstalled.